# How to get the last element(objects), position details in Raphael?

Tags: jquery, raphael

I am doing a loop function to make the circles, i decided to link the circles to drawing lines between the objects, so, the first circle is draw i should get the 'cx' and 'cy' of the object and i will start to draw the line.

for that, in case of jquery we can get the final element as using ':last' selector, i am trying with raphael, any one help me to get the last element of each drawing.

my function:

```
var paper = new Raphael('paper',500,500);
var circle1 = paper.circle(50,50,50).attr({fill:'green'});

var circle2 = paper.circle(200,50,50).attr({fill:'red'});

$(paper.node,':first').click(function(){
    alert(this.atrr('x'));
})


$(paper.node,':last').click(function(){
    alert(this.atrr('x'));
})
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mg39Z/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are not correctly setted, you should use it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/S6REC/

```
$('circle:first',paper.node).click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('cx'));
})


$('circle:last',paper.node).click(function(){ 
    alert($(this).attr('cx'));
})
```

Comment: still you are missing the semicolons

Answer (score 1):

@3gwebtrain

Try this:

```
var paper = new Raphael('paper',500,500);
var circle1 = paper.circle(50,50,50).attr({fill:'green'});
var circle2 = paper.circle(180,50,50).attr({fill:'red'});

jQuery(function($){

    var c1 = $('circle:first').attr("cx");
    var c2 = $('circle:last').attr("cx");
    $('circle:first').click(function(){
        alert(c1);
    });
    $('circle:last').click(function(){
        alert(c2);
    });

});
```

or find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mg39Z/5/